# Nhibernate Eager load when querying by primary key

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In my repository I am returning an object(`Chain`) by its primary key(`chainNumber`). `Chain` has a collection of steps(`ChainStep`).

How can I eager load the steps when querying by primary code?

Here is my repository code.

```
public Chain Get(string chainNumber)
{
    var chain = session.Get<Chain>(chainNumber);
    if (chain == null)
    {
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException(
            string.Format("Chain not found for number: {0}.", chainNumber));
    }
    return chain;
}
```

Here is my mapping:

```
public class ChainMap: ClassMap<Chain>
{
    public ChainMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ChainNumber).Length(4).Not.Nullable();
        //More properties
        HasMany(x => x.Steps).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell NHibernate to *always* eager-load the collection, you can use `.Not.LazyLoad()` in your mapping.  This should work for you:

```
public class ChainMap: ClassMap<Chain>
{
    public ChainMap()
    {
        // ...
        HasMany(x => x.Steps).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Inverse().Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

If there are simply specific times that you want to eager-load the collection, you could amend your Get method to use `Query`and `Fetch`:

```
public Chain Get(string chainNumber)
{
    var chain = session.Query<Chain>()
                    .Where(chain => chain.ChainNumber == chainNumber)
                    .Fetch(chain => chain.Steps)
                    .Single();

    if (chain == null)
    {
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException(
            string.Format("Chain not found for number: {0}.", chainNumber));
    }
    return chain;
}
```

This second approach has the advantage of allowing lazy-loading to remain your default for this type (for when the child collection might not be accessed immediately by other parts of your codebase).

*Note: the call to `Single` above will throw an exception if there's not exactly one match, so it is sort of redundant with your exception-throwing below*